# How to give the correct result based on answer combinations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a quiz wherein a user will select one of two options and based on pre determined combination sets, I will tell them what type of investor they're.

The javascript code looks like this:

```
const showAnswer = () => {
  let result
  answers.forEach(answer => {
    if (
    chosenAnswers.includes(answer.combination[0]) +
    chosenAnswers.includes(answer.combination[1]) +
    chosenAnswers.includes(answer.combination[2])
    ) {
      result = answer
      return
    }  else if (!result) {
      result = answers[2]
    }
  })
```

When I try to run the quiz, I get a default answer which says the user is risk neutral. Ideally, he/she should only see this if they didn't choose all A or all B. i.e, mixed and matched between the two options.

Would be helpful if someone could suggest how to rewrite the code so that it gives 'risk neutral' response only as a default.

Thank you in advance.

HTML Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>What type of investor are you?</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <h1>What type of investor are you?</h1>
            <p><i>This quiz is intended to be fun and educational and does not stand as a substitute for any professional psychological evaluation. The risk tolerance of an individual can depend on various factors such as their personality, financial situation, and experience with risk.</i></p>
            <div id ="questions"></div>
            <div id ="answer"></div>
        </section>
     <script src="quiz.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: [mcve] (html also) would help. All A is what risk, all B is what risk?

Comment: Thank you @depperm, will check this out. All A is risk averse and all B is risk seeking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic in the showAnswers method is concating and not checking as a combination. Use `&&` over `+`

```
const showAnswer = () => {


let result
  answers.forEach(answer => {
    if (
    chosenAnswers.includes(answer.combination[0]) &&
    chosenAnswers.includes(answer.combination[1]) &&
    chosenAnswers.includes(answer.combination[2])
    ) {
      result = answer
      return
    }  else if (!result) {
      result = answers[2]
    }
  })
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-mahavira-p3flzc?file=/src/index.js:5451-5792